# Problems Compiling OCILIB OCI Wrapper Library

Tags: c, oracle, oracle-call-interface

I'm trying to compile demo in `ocilib3.8.1/demo`. After successfully installing the `ocilib` library, I then compile demo source conn.c below :

```
#include "ocilib.h"

int main(void)
{
    OCI_Connection *cn;

    if (!OCI_Initialize(NULL, NULL, OCI_ENV_DEFAULT))
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    cn = OCI_ConnectionCreate("db", "usr", "pwd", OCI_SESSION_DEFAULT);

    printf("Server major    version : %i\n",   OCI_GetServerMajorVersion(cn));
    printf("Server minor    version : %i\n",   OCI_GetServerMinorVersion(cn));
    printf("Server revision version : %i\n\n", OCI_GetServerRevisionVersion(cn));
    printf("Connection      version : %i\n\n", OCI_GetVersionConnection(cn));

    OCI_Cleanup();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Compile using gcc :

```
$gcc -Wall conn.c -o conn.o -I/usr/local/include \
    -DOCI_IMPORT_LINKAGE -DOCI_CHARSET_ANSI
```

Error :

```
$ gcc -Wall conn.c -o conn.o -I/usr/local/include \
    -DOCI_IMPORT_LINKAGE -DOCI_CHARSET_ANSI
/tmp/ccMgFQri.o: In function `main':
conn.c:(.text+0x26): undefined reference to `OCI_Initialize'
conn.c:(.text+0x4f): undefined reference to `OCI_ConnectionCreate'
conn.c:(.text+0x63): undefined reference to `OCI_GetServerMajorVersion'
conn.c:(.text+0x82): undefined reference to `OCI_GetServerMinorVersion'
conn.c:(.text+0xa1): undefined reference to `OCI_GetServerRevisionVersion'
conn.c:(.text+0xc0): undefined reference to `OCI_GetVersionConnection'
conn.c:(.text+0xd6): undefined reference to `OCI_Cleanup'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm using redhat el5, gcc version 3.4.6 20060404 (Red Hat 3.4.6-4), instant client Release 10.2.0.5.0.

Thanks for help. I'm newbies in linux programming ..

Answer (score 3):

you have to link against ocilib !

add "-locilib" to the command line :)

Comment: May also need `-L` to (I guess) `/usr/local/lib` to find the library. And the `-o conn.o` argument won't be needed?

Comment: gcc -DOCI_IMPORT_LINKAGE -DOCI_CHARSET_ANSI  -L$ORACLE_HOME/lib -lclntsh  -L/usr/local/lib -locilib  conn.c   -o conn